Find replacement hook for this pannier?
The hook on a pannier broke (because someone rode into it).
The rail seems rivetted to the bag and not detachable, so I'd like to replace the hook[s] and not the rail.
I see some replacement kits online but without enough detail e.g. dimensions to see whether they're compatible.
Here's a photo:

The broken hook is on the right, the part facing downward should grasp the rail with the central prong fitting into it.


Do you recognise this as a rail for which I can buy a replacement hook?
The bag is a "Halfords Advanced" i.e. bought in the UK
The width of the rail look like 25 or 27 mm, or maybe one inch


You don't necessarily need a perfect match - you can get away with not fitting the width of the rail so long as there's good contact between flats on the hooks and flats on the  rail when you do the screws up.
In the past I've used Carradice C-system hooks as a replacement for others, but they're not what you need here. These Altura (Rixen & Kaul) might work though, with a different screw.
These Oxford ones fit in the same way as yours but I can't find dimensions or enough details to scale from a photo of the whole pannier.  They could be perfect or not work at all.
I have drilled the rivets out of a broken pannier in the past, to reuse the mounting hardware one something else.  It was rather tedious and I wouldn't recommend it on a  pannier you wanted to save.

Thank you the Oxford ones look perfect. A picture of the bag suggests that the rail's width is 26 mm => I ordered some, will see.

That looks like Ortlieb hardware, specifically the QL1 hooks. And they do sell spare parts. You'd probably want to replace both hooks, since the carry-strap seems to be permanently affixed to both of them.
However, looking closely at your picture, the part where the hook mates to the rail seems to be more squared-off on your panniers, and more rounded on the Ortliebs. So I'm not sure it's the same thing.

Thanks, the I'm not sure that's the right size. If this is a Q1 rail -- https://www.ortlieb.com/fr_fr/long-4-hole-ql1-bracket-with-screws-without-hooks -- then given that is 31 cm long, it looks like it's only 16 mm wide, so about half the width of the other. And here is a photo of the hooks, yes their attachment is "rounded" and not "square"  -- https://www.ortlieb.com/fr_fr/ql1-mounting-hooks

They're not QL2.1 either

Maybe you could attach an Ortlieb rail? Drill out the rivets, patch the holes and attach an Ortlieb rail + hooks.
